# can multiple threads access a database at the same time via JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a class which uses `JDBC` to interact with SQL Server and `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and... .now is it possible that multiple threads use this class(not a shared object, each thread uses a new object of this class) to access database at the same time?

Comment: I would say that depends on the database, but if each thread is requesting its own connection, it's likely that the DB engine will reject/block these requests until it is capable of handling the requests.  It will also come down to the DB engines capabilities, thinks like support for transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , It is possible.

> If each new object is sharing the same object of JDBC Connection then
>   it will slow down your database access.
>
> If each new object has its own JDBC Connection object then it won't
>   slow down the database access . But this will create multiple
>   connections with your database which will increase load on database.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is only standard for how to communicate with some SQL server over Java code. Multi thread doesn't have any impact on JDBC, if your code is thread safe, you create transactions when you needed etc. all will be fine

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is not a class, it's a standard. However, you can have multiple connections to the database (usually a connection pool managed by a container). Each thread will get a connection and execute operations on the database. The usage of transactions ensures data consistency and integrity.

Comment: what do you mean by "connection pool managed by a container"?

Comment: If your application runs in a JEE application server (like WebLogic, WebSphere, JBoss) then the server will provide you a DB connection pool: this means that the server creates a number of DB connections and gives them to a client that needs to do an operation on the DB. When the client does not need the connection anymore the server is can pass that connection to another client. This is more efficient since establishing a connection from scratch is a heavy operation.